# How to create Logic App using Rest api or Azure functions, without opening the azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub, rest

Through Azure portal I am able to create **logic app** and configure workflows, but I don't want to create anything using the portal, I want to create and configure workflows for **logic app using RestApi or azure functions**, So basically without opening the portal i should be able to create/update logic app, I have gone through many documents and unable to find data related to my required.How can I achieve this, Is it possible or not?
If its possible please provide the documentation link to refer

Comment: I think you can try to use Azure function Powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell

Comment: do u mean we can write a azure function to execute the powershell commands? i want to to be done through an api/azure functions, so that from my UI i can just call the api to create/update the logic app

Comment: Yes. You can run Azure function through powershell and call that function as Rest API

Comment: ok, i will try that, but how do i create the logic app using that api, I mean what steps needs to be done for creation of logic app through restapi

Comment: First Create logic app thro powershell then you can use same PowerShell command in Azure function

Answer (score 0):

I got the restapi, it is already present, check the link below, using that i am able to create and list the logicapps, we need to pass the respective trigger and actions along with bearer token

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/createorupdate